# Java SQL error with my own MySQL server SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, mysql

I have programmed an Discord bot that uses MySQL all great on my PC but after uploading it to my Server it comes following error:

```
Thu Oct 25 02:04:23 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

On "public" server's its function's normaly (db4free.net) only this message is showing:

```
Thu Oct 25 02:01:04 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

My Code:

(It fail's on "public static void connect(JDA jda)")

```
package org.spielearena.core;

import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Guild;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.TextChannel;
import org.spielearena.util.RandomString;
import org.spielearena.util.config;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class mysql {

    public static Connection con = null;
    public static ArrayList<TextChannel> asyncChannel = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void connect(JDA jda) {
        try {
            if (con == null) {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + config.config.getString("config.mysql.server") + ":" + config.config.getString("config.mysql.port") + "/" + config.config.getString("config.mysql.database") + "?autoReconnect=true", config.config.getString("config.mysql.user"), config.config.getString("config.mysql.pass"));
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "keys`  ( `serverkey` VARCHAR(500), `serverid` VARCHAR(500), `channelid` VARCHAR(500), `async` VARCHAR(500)) ENGINE = InnoDB;");
                ps.executeUpdate();
                ps = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "toDiscord`  ( `serverkey` VARCHAR(500), `message` VARCHAR(5000)) ENGINE = InnoDB;");
                ps.executeUpdate();
                ps = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "fromDiscord`  ( `serverkey` VARCHAR(500), `message` VARCHAR(50000), `unixTime` VARCHAR(500)) ENGINE = InnoDB;");
                ps.executeUpdate();
                ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "keys");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    if (!existsGuildAndChannel(jda, rs.getString("serverid"), rs.getString("channelid"))) {
                        ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "keys WHERE serverkey='" + rs.getString("serverkey") + "'");
                        ps.executeUpdate();
                    } else {
                        if (rs.getString("async").equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                            asyncChannel.add(jda.getGuildById(rs.getString("serverid")).getTextChannelById(rs.getString("channelid")));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
               throw new Exception("Internal error #001");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("MySQL error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static boolean existsGuildAndChannel(JDA jda, String guild, String channel) {
        try {
            return jda.getGuildById(guild).getTextChannelById(channel).canTalk();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return false;
    }

    public static void disconnect() {
        try {
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
                con = null;
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Internal error #001");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("MySQL error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void sync(String message, TextChannel channel) {
        try {
            if (con != null) {
                if (asyncChannel.contains(channel)) {
                    ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "keys WHERE channelid='" + channel.getId() + "' AND serverid='" + channel.getGuild().getId() + "';");
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "fromDiscord (serverkey, message, unixTime) VALUES ('" + rs.getString("serverkey") + "', '" + message + "', '" + Integer.toString(((int)(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L))) + "')");
                        ps.execute();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("MySQL error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void sync(JDA jda) {
        try {
            if (con != null) {
                ArrayList<TextChannel> asyncChannel1 = new ArrayList<>();
                ResultSet rs2 = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "keys");
                while (rs2.next()) {
                    if (!existsGuildAndChannel(jda, rs2.getString("serverid"), rs2.getString("channelid"))) {
                        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "keys WHERE serverkey='" + rs2.getString("serverkey") + "'");
                        ps.executeUpdate();
                    } else {
                        if (rs2.getString("async").equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                            asyncChannel1.add(jda.getGuildById(rs2.getString("serverid")).getTextChannelById(rs2.getString("channelid")));
                        }
                    }
                }
                asyncChannel = asyncChannel1;
                ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "toDiscord");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "toDiscord WHERE serverkey='" + rs.getString("serverkey") + "' AND message='" + rs.getString("message") + "'");
                    ps.execute();
                    ResultSet rs1 = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "keys WHERE serverkey='" + rs.getString("serverkey") + "'");
                    while (rs1.next()) {
                        if (!existsGuildAndChannel(jda, rs1.getString("serverid"), rs1.getString("channelid"))) {
                            ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "keys WHERE serverkey='" + rs.getString("serverkey") + "'");
                            ps.executeUpdate();
                        } else {
                            jda.getGuildById(rs1.getString("serverid")).getTextChannelById(rs1.getString("channelid")).sendMessage(rs.getString("message")).queue();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Internal error #001");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("MySQL error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static String generateKey(Guild guild, TextChannel channel, Boolean async) {
        try {
            if (con != null) {
                String asy = "no";
                if (async) {
                    asy = "yes";
                    asyncChannel.add(channel);
                }
                RandomString rnd = new RandomString(32, new Random());
                String key = "";
                boolean finish = false;
                try {
                    ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "keys WHERE serverid='" + guild.getId() + "'");
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        if (rs.getString("channelid").equalsIgnoreCase(channel.getId())) {
                            return rs.getString("serverkey");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("MySQL error: " + e);
                }
                while (!finish) {
                    key = rnd.nextString();
                    try {
                        boolean alredyExists = false;
                        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "keys WHERE serverkey='" + key + "'");
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            alredyExists = true;
                        }
                        if (!alredyExists) {
                            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + config.config.getString("config.mysql.prefix") + "keys (serverkey, serverid, channelid, async) VALUES ('" + key + "', '" + guild.getId() + "', '" + channel.getId() + "', '" + asy + "')");
                            ps.execute();
                            finish = true;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("MySQL error: " + e);
                    }
                }
                return key;
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Internal error #001");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("MySQL error: " + e);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

My Server:

5.7.24 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Linux version 4.9.0-8-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u6 (2018-10-08)

openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-1~deb9u1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: Instead of `System.out.println("MySQL error: " + e);` printing the error, try to print the stack trace.

Comment: What's the use of catching exceptions if you are going to do this: `catch (Exception e) {}`?

Comment: @clinomaniac thx 4 you'r answere it helped me alot i have found the error it is the Time Zone: https://hastebin.com/izivujupux.sql